# Как интегрировать сессию в WordPress из Yii2

Tags: wordpress, yii2

Мне нужно вывести на странице с контентом реализованном на ворд прессе, сессию из yii как это сделать?

Пробовал получить значение через Curl, но сессии как я понимаю не существует.

Пожалуйста помогите! Если есть решение на php , буду особенно благодарен!

Comment: Как я понимаю, нужно добавить настройки в конфиге 'user' что бы внутри сайта были доступы к сессии